# Condition $abc=k^3$ question.

Tags: inequality

In math lesson at school, my teacher showed us a skill when seeing the inequality which has the condition $abc=k^3$. He showed us 5 types of way to change variable, I wrote them down here:
$$\begin{align}
(a,b,c) &\mapsto (\frac{k}{a},\frac{k}{b},\frac{k}{c})\\
(a,b,c) &\mapsto (\frac{ka}{b},\frac{kb}{c},\frac{kc}{a})\\
(a,b,c) &\mapsto (\frac{kb}{a},\frac{kc}{b},\frac{ka}{c})\\
(a,b,c) &\mapsto(\frac{ka^2}{bc},\frac{kb^2}{ca},\frac{kc^2}{ab})\\
(a,b,c) &\mapsto(\frac{kbc}{a^2},\frac{kca}{b^2},\frac{kab}{c^2})
\end{align}$$
Our homework is to find when we should use these types of changing variable. I pick 2 problems for looking the way for solving our homework.

***P1***: Let: $a,b,c>0$ such that $abc=1$. Prove that:$$\frac{1}{(1+a)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+b)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+c)^2}+\frac{2}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)} \geq 1$$

Solution 1:

WLOG, we assume that: $a,b$ are both bigger or smaller than $1$.

So have: $(a-1)(b-1) \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow  2(ab+1) \geq (a+1)(b+1)$

From here get: $$\frac{2}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}\geq \frac{1}{(ab+1)(c+1)}=\frac{abc}{(ab+abc)(1+c)}=\frac{c}{(1+c)^2}$$

Using this lemma: For $x,y \geq 0$ we have: $$\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+y)^2} \geq \frac{1}{1+xy}$$

So have: $$\begin{align}
LHS \geq \ &\frac{1}{1+ab} + \frac{1}{(1+c)^2} +  \frac{c}{(1+c)^2}\\
&= \frac{abc}{abc+ab} +\frac{1}{(1+c)^2} +  \frac{c}{(1+c)^2}\\
&= \frac{c}{c+1} + \frac{1}{(1+c)^2} +  \frac{c}{(1+c)^2}\\
&=  1.\end{align}$$

Solution 2:

From the condition, and our topic, let: $$(a,b,c) \mapsto(\frac{yz}{x^2},\frac{zx}{y^2},\frac{xy}{z^2})$$

So our inequality can be rewritten as:

$$\sum \frac{x^4}{(x^2+yz)^2}+\frac{2x^2y^2z^2}{(x^2+yz)(y^2+zx)(x^2+xy)}\geq 1$$

Using Cauchy-Schwartz: $(x^2+yz)^2 \leq (x^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2)$

So: $$\sum \frac{x^4}{(x^2+yz)^2} \geq \sum \frac{x^4}{(x^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2} = 1 - \frac{2x^2y^2z^2}{(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(z^2+x^2)} $$

From there, we just need to prove:

$$(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(z^2+x^2) \geq (x^2+yz)(y^2+zx)(z^2+xy)$$
which is true by Cauchy-Schwarz: $x^2+yz \leq \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2)}$

After this, I see that Lemma:For $x,y \geq 0$ we have: $$\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+y)^2} \geq \frac{1}{1+xy}$$ is a strong one for the condition $xyz=1$

***P2***: Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $abc=1$. Prove that: $$\frac{1}{(1+a)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+b)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+c)^2}\geq \frac{3}{4}$$

Solution 1:

Using the lemma on ***P1***, we need to prove: $$\frac{1}{1+ab}+\frac{1}{(1+c)^2}\geq \frac{3}{4}\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{1+c}+\frac{1}{(1+c)^2}\geq \frac{3}{4}\Leftrightarrow (1-c)^2 \geq 0$$

When add one more variable $d$ we get **China TST 2009**.

Put: $$(a,b,c,d) \mapsto (\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{y}, \frac{t}{z},\frac{x}{t})$$

Now using Cauchy-Schwarz and AM-GM:

$$LHS\geq \frac{[x(x+t)+y(y+x)+z(z+y)+t(t+z)]^2}{\sum (x+y)^2(x+t)^2}=\frac{[(x+y)^2+(y+z)^2+(z+t)^2+(t+x)^2]^2}{4[(x+y)^2+(z+t)^2][(x+t)^2+(y+z)^2]}\geq 1$$

**Can anyone explain why they using Cauchy-Schwarz like that?**

After 2 problems, I can't find a reason why they can change variable like that? If I'm in a test, trying all of ways to change variable is ineffective way. I know that I need to change variable for homogenization but are there some ways show us which type of way for changing variable effectively without trying to put all 5 types changing variable?
Thank you a lots for your help!!